# YouTube API v3 - can't get a proper channel ID

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I need to get a user channel ID after oAuth2 login on a web app, to this time I was doing it like that:

```
  var response = "";
  gapi.client.request({
    'method': 'GET',
    'path': 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels',
    'params': {'part': 'snippet', 'mine': 'true', 'fields': fields},
    'scope': scope,
    'access_token': token
  }).execute(function(response) {
    if (response["items"][0]["id"] != null) {
      app.user.id = response["items"][0]["id"];
    } else {
      console.log("Error: " + response);
      // gapi error
    }
  });
```

But when I use the code above and user logges out and logges back in using another account, it still will return a channel ID of this first account, even if the access token is associated with the second account. So I come up with this:

```
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest(),
  url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels",
  params = "part=id&mine=true&access_token=" + token;
  http.open("GET", url, true);
  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
      if (http.responseText["items"][0]["id"] != null) {
        app.user.id = http.responseText["items"][0]["id"];
      } else {
        console.log("Error: " + http.responseText);
      }
    } else {
      console.log("Error: " + http.responseText);
    }
  }
  http.send(params);
```

Which always gives me this response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Required parameter: part",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "part"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Required parameter: part"
 }
}
```

And I don't know why...

Comment: try using ```url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&mine=true&access_token=' + token;``` and ```http.send(null);```

Comment: @SaadMehmood consider post your comment as an answer. Also please include where `http.send(null);` should be added.